# How to store data in Chrome Storage API with dynamic key value pair?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am learning JS these days and am building a Chrome Extension. In that I am storing user data. Now I can successfully store and retrieve data but here is the catch. I want to store the key value pair dynamically. As in whatever the user provides should be the key of the object. Below is my code.

The idea is to create a dynamic key value pair depending upon the user input. Right now a key value pair is created with the literal name `Vname:{}`. However I want that to be dynamically created depending upon the user input.

```
"use strict";

// chrome.storage.sync.clear()

chrome.storage.sync.get(null,function(result){
    for (let k in result){
        console.log(k)
        result[k]["Page1 Title"] = "Url1"
        for(let kk in result[k]){
            console.log(kk)
            console.log(result[k][kk])
        }
    }



})



let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){

    let vname = prompt("Name of the view?")

    chrome.storage.sync.set({vname:{}})

    
    



})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array style access to create objects

Ex:

```
const key = 'vname'
chrome.storage.sync.set({[key]:{}})
```

[Read more here](https://time2hack.com/different-ways-to-create-objects-in-javascript/#array-index-access-in-object-notation-and-object-assign)